# IIS7 ip address blocking error page

Tags: iis-7

We have a website which is protected by IIS7' IP restrictions module. The persons who do not have access get a 403.6 error page from IIS7. But I want to put up a custom error page. I tried several things with custom error pages, but it looks like they are not even touched by IIS because of this restriction. is there another way to do this?